# Is there any seasonal VAR or VARMA algorithm?

Tags: r, time-series, python, vector-autoregression, seasonality

As I understand, **VAR** algorithms doesn't work with seasonal data. I mean, seasonal components are not in the autoregression equation. But, if I want find dependencies between several time series, that have seasonality, what should I do?

Sure, I can use RNN. But I want to know, is there a solution for VAR or VARMA.

Also I know, that there's a **sVARMA** in R. But I can't understand its [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/MTS/man/sVARMA.html) and how to predict values.